# Having trouble with saving rows in database using stored procedures in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures

My code is working perfectly, it says the row was saved but when I take a look in the database no row was saved. Can you help me please?

I want to save a row using a stored procedures, the `checkifusernameexist` is working but the save function do not save the data.

Here's my code, hope you can understand it.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace storedprocedures
{
    public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public string GetConnectionString()
        {
            return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["practiceDatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        }

        private void executeAdd(string username, string password)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_CreateUser", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("userName",userName.Text);
            SqlParameter p2 = new SqlParameter("password",password.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p2);

            SqlDataReader dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (dReader.HasRows)
            {
                dReader.Read();     
                Label3.Text="Record Added!";
            }
            else
            {
                Label3.Text="User Error";
            }
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
            con.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_CheckIfUserNameExist",con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("userName", userName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);
            SqlDataReader dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (dReader.HasRows)
            {
                dReader.Read();
                this.Label3.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                this.Label3.Text = "Username already exist!";
            }
            else
            {
                this.Label3.Text = "congrats! nanalo ka na!";
                this.userName.Text = "";
                this.password.Text = "";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to **show us** your connection string!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` for adding records.

Comment: The return from cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() is an integer, which you can check for how many rows were modified with the query.